# is it possible to use any external or 3rd party storage system for artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

We were looking for the possibility to configure jFrog Artifactory to work with other object storage  systems...

Is it possible? if yes could you please guide ?

Comment: The files are being stored somewhere, I guess the question was if and how to store them in somewhere else than the local filesystem.

Comment: @gba yes. We modified the binarystore.xml file added the s3 bucket details. and restarted artifactory.  After this we tried to deploy some artifacts and when we checked under "Admin-Advanced-> Storage" its showing s3 however the size is not showing but cache FS the size is showing ? Is this the expected behavior ? what is cache fs in this case, inside the satisfactory server also we could fined a directory calle d s3-startup with no data. Also a directory called cache is storing the artifacts .. is it correct ?

Comment: Cache-fs is a layer of cache before S3, it will cache files for download. It is usually much faster than S3 since it uses the local file system Artifactory is installed on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artifactory support a very large number of external file storages, including all the large cloud object storages:

- Amazon S3 compatible storage
- Google Cloud Storage
- Azure Blob Storage
- Any kind of local mounts
- NFS
- Database (Full DB)

The file storage is very configurable with multiple layers like cache and sharding.

Please read: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+the+Filestore

Comment: tried as per the document, but it showing like artifacts are storing cache fs in storage console window (cache directory inside the server)

Comment: The files are cached in the local file system, LRU based cache, limited by size (configurable). The files should also be uploaded to S3.

Comment: so its also present in local server as well ?  so what is the advantage by storing in S3.  entire s3 artifacts also will be present locally ?

Comment: Not the entire storage will be stored locally. Only the least recently used files will be cached locally. The size of the cace will be limited by configuration. This will give you speed and ability to scale up to a theoretically unlimited storage (S3).

Comment: is there any performance issue by s3 storage ?.. i have configured now to use s3 but how can verify the speed or perfomance ?

Comment: When working with S3, your speed depends on the network, latency etc. serving from local disk is faster. The default S3 templates has cache implemented already. To test you can use tools like Apache Benchmark.

Comment: Now we did this in the standalone setup only. But if we do in clustered environment of Artifactory, ie we have 2 nodes artifactory, which is active active. I read from the document site that, "High Availability clusters will need to use a shared mount for the S3 provider Using the S3 storage provider (or the s3 chain template), will require a shared mount for cluster. This is since only the primary node will handle the object store interaction, while all of the nodes, will be able to add files to the shared mount eventual directory." . so if primary get down?how will work

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we're using a two node, HA cluster, of Artifactory 7.x and it points to Hitachi Content Platform (HCP) which is S3 compliant.  Works great!  We cache 500GB locally and then the rest is on our HCP.

Before implementing this, we double checked with support on regards to the wording of their documentation.  They will, in fact, support any S3 compliant system to be used as Artifactory's backend storage provider.

We configured it via these instructions:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/S3+Object+Storage

Our binarystore.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<config version="2">
    <chain>
        <provider type="cache-fs" id="cache-fs-eventual-s3">
            <provider type="sharding-cluster" id="sharding-cluster-eventual-s3">
                <dynamic-provider type="remote" id="remote-s3"/>
                <sub-provider type="eventual-cluster" id="eventual-cluster-s3">
                    <provider type="retry" id="retry-s3">
                        <provider type="s3" id="s3"/>
                    </provider>
                </sub-provider>
            </provider>
        </provider>
    </chain>
    <provider type="cache-fs" id="cache-fs-eventual-s3">
        <maxCacheSize>500000000000</maxCacheSize>
        <cacheProviderDir>cache</cacheProviderDir>
    </provider>
    <provider type="sharding-cluster" id="sharding-cluster-eventual-s3">
        <writeBehavior>crossNetworkStrategy</writeBehavior>
        <readBehavior>crossNetworkStrategy</readBehavior>
        <redundancy>1</redundancy>
        <property name="zones" value="local,remote"/>
    </provider>
    <provider type="eventual-cluster" id="eventual-cluster-s3">
        <zone>local</zone>
    </provider>
    <provider type="retry" id="retry-s3">
        <maxTrys>10</maxTrys>
    </provider>
    <provider type="s3" id="s3">
        <bucketName>Artifactory</bucketName>
        <endpoint>http://namespace.tenant.cluster.com</endpoint>
        <credential>REMOVED</credential>
        <port>80</port>
        <identity>REMOVED</identity>
        <httpsOnly>false</httpsOnly>
        <s3AwsVersion>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256</s3AwsVersion>
        <property name="httpclient.max-connections" value="300"/>
        <property name="s3service.disable-dns-buckets" value="true"/>
    </provider>
    <provider type="remote" id="remote-s3">
        <checkPeriod>15000</checkPeriod>
        <connectionTimeout>5000</connectionTimeout>
        <socketTimeout>30000</socketTimeout>
        <maxConnections>300</maxConnections>
        <connectionRetry>2</connectionRetry>
        <zone>remote</zone>
    </provider>
</config>
```

I also posted a guide on my personal blog back when we first set it up with Artifactory 6.x.  You can find that here:
https://www.tyler-wright.com/using-hitachi-content-platform-as-backend-storage-for-jfrogs-artifactory/